# Minify and Unminify String Function

Tags: dart, encryption, cryptography

I have a string like `3ZwgC3xOuq1LpbL4Ajs5`. I want to create a function that take that string and convert like `3DV3A2` etc. It will shorten the string and likewise give me the previous string when I export the shortened string.

I am using `Dart` btw.

`3ZwgC3xOuq1LpbL4Ajs5` -------- CONVERT TO --------> `3DV3A2` 
`3DV3A2` -------- CONVERT TO --------> `3ZwgC3xOuq1LpbL4Ajs5`

Comment: There are more 20-character strings than 6-character strings. It's impossible for there to be a 1:1 map between these spaces. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle  For this to work, you will need to store the mapping somewhere that it can be looked up (this is how URL-shorteners work; they have a database of mappings).

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to write a function that will compress every string. At best you can write a function that will compress most, but not all, strings.

Compression works by reducing redundancy at some level. Your example string does not appear to have a lot of redundancy, so is probably not very compressible.